# creating a progression bar while a webpage is loading using web worker

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-worker

cause i have high res images... and a lot of background images n graphics.. thats why i want to the webpage to load all contains ,then display when  its all loaded.. but at the same time when contains are been downloaded  i want webpage to show a progression bar display the progress of the downloaded contains....

and  is it possible that the downloads to be done using webworks so that it does not slow down a browser

i have tried the display none property but it does not cut it

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you properly, you want your page to show a loading screen while the page hasn't fully loaded. To accomplish this, add this right after your `<body>` tag:

```
<style>
    #load-bg {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #000;
        opacity: 0.75;
    }
    #load-msg {
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        height: 20px;
        width: 100px;
        background: #fff;
    }
</style>

<div id="load-bg">
    <div id="load-msg">
        <p>Loading...</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    window.onload(hideLoad());

    function hideLoad(){
        document.getElementById('load-bg').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StashCat/V9ccf/1/)